# Swift: Create array with different custom types

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm making a registration form app. This lets users create questions and display the created questions in a UITableView. Users can create 2 types of questions, text input(using textfields) and multiple choice(using segmentedcontrol). Here is the class I created to make this happen.

```
class Question {
var Label: String
var required: Int

// create question
init (Label: String, required: Int) {
    self.Label = Label
    self.required = required

    if (self.required == 0) {
        self.Label = self.Label + " *"
    }
}
}

class textInput: Question {
var placeHolder: String

init (placeHolder: String, Label: String, required: Int) {
    self.placeHolder = placeHolder
    super.init(Label: Label, required: required)
}
}

class multiChoice: Question {
var answers: [String]

init(answers: [String], Label: String, required: Int) {
    self.answers = answers
    super.init(Label: Label, required: required)
}
}
```

I will need to populate an array with textInput or multiChoice types which will be displayed in the UITableView. In C++ you can use templates to accomplish this arbitrary type issue. Is there a way to do that in Swift, and if so could I get pointers on how to do it with these classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off. Change your `Question` class as follows:

```
var required: Bool

init (Label: String, required: Bool) {
    self.Label = Label
    self.required = required

    if self.required {
        self.Label = self.Label + " *"
    }
}
```

Next, you can use an array of type `[Question]` to achieve what you're looking for. Then you can do specific actions based on the class using `guard` or `if let` structures.

Comment: That won't work. Lets say I have the following. questionsArray: [Question]. Lets say I'm iterating through the array and I get to a textInput element. I cannot call the following statement without getting an error, questionsArray[i].placeholder. The Question base class does not have access to "placeholder". That's why I need an array that will hold multiple custom types.

Comment: `if let question = questionsArray[i] as? textInput { print(question.placeholder) }`

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish what you want that is very clean and type safe is to create an `enum` with associated values for the different types that you will be using. Then you can create an array of `enum` values and unwrap them using a `switch` to get at what you want.

```
class QuestionBase {
    var label: String
    var required: Bool

    // create question
    init (label: String, required: Bool) {
        self.label = label
        self.required = required

        if required {
            self.label = self.label + " *"
        }
    }
}

class TextInputQuestion: QuestionBase {
    var placeHolder: String

    init (placeHolder: String, label: String, required: Bool) {
        self.placeHolder = placeHolder
        super.init(label: label, required: required)
    }
}

class MultiChoiceQuestion: QuestionBase {
    var answers: [String]

    init(answers: [String], label: String, required: Bool) {
        self.answers = answers
        super.init(label: label, required: required)
    }
}

enum Question {
    case TextInput(TextInputQuestion)
    case MultiChoice(MultiChoiceQuestion)
}

let q1 = TextInputQuestion(placeHolder: "placeholder", label: "q1", required: true)
let q2 = MultiChoiceQuestion(answers: ["answer1", "answer2"], label: "q2", required: false)

let questions: [Question] = [.TextInput(q1), .MultiChoice(q2)]

for question in questions {
    switch question {
    case .TextInput(let question):
        print(question.placeHolder)
    case .MultiChoice(let question):
        print(question.answers)
    }
}
```

`enum`s are very powerful this way. The array is all of one type: `Question`. The associated values can be of any type. You could have a `TrueFalse` `case`, or even an `Essay` `case`.

I rewrote much of your code - it violated a lot of the Swift style guidelines and it made it very hard to read. Type names, like `class` names, should all be `LikeThis` (starting with an uppercase letter), while properties should all be in `camelCase` (starting with a lowercase letter). And I renamed some of the types just to make it more clear what the intentions were. You can take those changes or leave them.

Comment: Came up with a much easier solution similar to the ones in the comments above. As far as changes to the class, I have made many of those changes, except to the required variable. It will remain an int because it is much easier that way.